# Hiding Next Visible Siblings Via If Statement Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search filter function but I'm 99% certain the issue does not lie there.

I first call the search filter then run an if statement to determine if I should hide the row or not.

Imagine I have the following visible table rows after performing a search:

```
<tr>
  <td class="time">content<td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>result</td>
<tr>
</tr>
  <td>result</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="time">content<td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="time">content<td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="time">content<td>
</tr>
```

**My goal is to hide all td elements which have a time class iff they are proceeded by a row containing a td element with the same class of time.** Therefore the if statement should hide the last three rows only in my above example, ie.:

```
<tr>
  <td class="time">content<td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>result</td>
<tr>
</tr>
  <td>result</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
$('td.time').parent().each(function() {
  if($(this).siblings().first().children('td.time').length > 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

The above works but only if my search returns a single result. If another result exists following a different time row that time row is mistakenly hidden.

Below is what I currently have but it simply hides all time rows even though theoretically it makes sense:

```
$('td.time').parent().each(function() {
  if($(this).next(':visible').children('.time')) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

My only explanation is that with .next() it's only looking at the next td.time parent rather than the next of all visible table rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to parent tr and you probably do not need to use each over here to hide all next `tr` having `td` with class `time` .

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dGrDL/)**

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr:has(td.time)').hide();
```

Comment: This answer acts exactly like my first solution. It works for single search results but any remaining results lose their time "heading". See example here: http://cole.quinnchrzan.com/tv

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant but [try this](http://jsbin.com/eqadej/2)

```
$(".time").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("tr").next("tr").find(".time").length > 0) {
        $(this).parent("tr").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer does nothing. All time "headings" are still visible when searching. See example here: http://cole.quinnchrzan.com/tv/index2.php If I try to specify .next("tr:visible") it still acts the same way.